# Laravel is safe request data from ID?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have got a question about the Laravel routing system. Usually, when I create a controller, Laravel automatically builds some "standard" functions like index, create, show, etc. The most part of this functions usually requires the ID of the resource but I'm not pretty sure that it the best (and safe) way to do it.

Ex. Laravel creates this function:

```
 /**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}
```

I know that $id means "everything that can be useful to indicate that resource" and so I could use other database field (ex. slug), however it have to point the same data...so what is the difference between this two approch?

Comment: If you want, you could perhaps, authenticate users (using cookies and session) before running certain methods. If anything else, you could limit on what kind of input you expect and output you might reveal. All depends on your system architecture.

Comment: It's a good advice, i'll follow it.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by unsafe. In mysql primary keys are usually incremented by 1 each time a new record is created. This means that no more than one record in a given table can only ever have the same primary key. The only time this would be unsafe is if a user tried to pass an id which belonged to data which wasn't theirs. It is up to you, to ensure that users cannot access other user's data, the primary key you use isn't really related to this.